# Initialize property that has default value from protocol

Tags: swift

I would like to initialize `maxHeight` only sometimes, so I wanted to have default value in protocol. However, I can not get it to work this way. Any hint to what direction should I look without having to declare `maxHeight` as Optional, or by passing default value in inits?

```
protocol Player: {
    var minHeight: CGFloat { get set }
    var maxHeight: CGFloat { get set }
}

extension Player {
    var maxHeight: CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
}

struct SmallPlayer: Player {
    public var minHeight: CGFloat
    public var maxHeight: CGFloat
    public init(minHeight: CGFloat) {
        self.minHeight = minHeight
        /// ERROR HERE: does not initialize all properties
        /// HOW TO INIT TO DEFAULT PROTOCOL VALUE? 
    }

public init(minHeight: CGFloat, maxHeight: CGFloat) {
    self.init(minHeight: minHeight)
    maxHeight = maxHeight
}
}
```

Comment: You have declared your protocol properties to be gettable _and_ settable but properties like this can not be represented by a computed (or constant) property like you have since they can only be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make `maxHeight` `static` so that you can use it as a default value for an instance property. I'd also suggest renaming it to `defaltMaxHeight` to clarify its meaning.

Unrelated to your question, but you should swap the implementation of the 2 inits - the default/designated init should be the one with the largest number of input arguments and the ones with less input arguments (using default argument values) should be calling the one with more input arguments, not the other way around.

```
protocol Player {
    var minHeight: CGFloat { get set }
    var maxHeight: CGFloat { get set }
}

extension Player {
    static var defaultMaxHeight: CGFloat {
        50
    }
}

struct SmallPlayer: Player {
  public var minHeight: CGFloat
  public var maxHeight: CGFloat

  public init(minHeight: CGFloat) {
    self.init(minHeight: minHeight, maxHeight: Self.defaultMaxHeight)
  }

  public init(minHeight: CGFloat, maxHeight: CGFloat) {
    self.minHeight = minHeight
    self.maxHeight = maxHeight
  }
}
```